# Cannot input password when selecting network SSID to perform internet recovery

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, internet-recovery

So after hitting command + R I am brought to a screen that prompts me to select my wifi network. Once I select my network SSID I get a field where I can input the password to my network however I am unable to select the field to enter my password. There is a lock icon to the left of the password entry field and a spinning indicator on the right.

As a result I am unable to perform an internet recovery as I cannot connect to internet.

Comment: I can’t seem to locate a document saying which WiFi protocols are supported, any chance you can use ethernet or another physical network?

Answer (score 1):

Are you connecting to a WPA2 Enterprise network (like the ones found at a school or job)? These networks require an additional certificate to be installed which is unsupported in the simplified Recovery Mode.

Also won't connect to Wi-Fi if you need to click Accept (like the ones in coffee shops and hotels).

Can you use the network normally from a different device? If yes then the network is not compatible with Recovery Mode.